# linq to sql: combine 2 queries and get sum foreach user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

It's almost working, but the sum is the same for all users. I think I need to fetch the UserId from Users so I can use it in the where clause, but i dont't know how to do it. I tried adding .GroupBy(s => s.User.Id) but it doesnt work.
VIEW

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
        {
        <tr>
                <td>@item.FullName</td>

                <td>@Model.PoengNC</td>
                <td>@Model.PoengDNC</td>
                <td>@Model.SumPoeng</td>
        </tr>
        }
```

ACTION

var model = new ViewModel();

```
        var users= db.Users
            .Where(s => s.IsActive).ToList();

        var countPoengNC = db.Resultater
            .Where(d => d.Stevne.Stevnetype.StevneTypeNavn == "NC" 
            && d.Stevne.StevneDato.Value.Year == 2016 && d.PoengNc != null )
            .GroupBy(s => s.User.Id)
            .Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(r => r.PoengNc).FirstOrDefault())
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.PoengNc).Take(2);

        int maximumDNC = 6 - countPoengNC.Count();

        var poengNC = db.Resultater
            .Where(d => d.Stevne.Stevnetype.StevneTypeNavn == "NC"
            && d.Stevne.StevneDato.Value.Year == 2016 && d.PoengNc != null)
            .GroupBy(s => s.User.Id)
            .Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(r => r.PoengNc).FirstOrDefault())
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.PoengNc).Take(2).Sum(d => d.PoengNc);

        var poengDNC = db.Resultater
            .Where(d => d.Stevne.Stevnetype.StevneTypeNavn == "DNC"
            && d.Stevne.StevneDato.Value.Year == 2016 && d.PoengNc != null )
            .GroupBy(s => s.User.Id)
            .Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(r => r.PoengNc).FirstOrDefault())
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.PoengNc).Take(maximumDNC).Sum(d => d.PoengNc);

        model.Users= users;
        model.PoengNC = poengNC;
        model.PoengDNC = poengDNC;
        model.SumPoeng = poengNC + poengDNC;

        return View(model);
```

VIEWMODEL

```
public class NorgescupenViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
    public int? PoengNC { get; set; }
    public int? PoengDNC { get; set; }
    public decimal? SumPoeng { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you have a big mistake in your model design, you have to make your model properties as a method in user class, or you can user a dictionary to bind each user to its sum values

Comment: yes i thought so. Im having difficulties to understand this when it becomes too complex, so I often end up to write code in the view instad of the controller. Im still learning, so hopefully I will actually understand what I'm doing sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. Here is what I ended up with.

```
var poengNC = db.Resultater
            .Where(d => d.Stevne.Stevnetype.StevneTypeNavn == "NC"
            && d.Stevne.StevneDato.Value.Year == 2016 && d.PoengNc != null)
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.PoengNc).Take(2).ToList();

        var poengDNC = db.Resultater
            .Where(d => d.Stevne.Stevnetype.StevneTypeNavn == "DNC"
            && d.Stevne.StevneDato.Value.Year == 2016 && d.PoengNc != null )
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.PoengNc).Take(6).ToList();

        var totalNC = poengNC.Union(poengDNC)
            .GroupBy(s => s.User.FullName)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                //SumPoeng = s.Sum(a => a.PoengNc),
                SumPoeng = s.Sum(a => a.PoengNc),
                Navn = s.Key
            })
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.SumPoeng)
            .ToList();
```